# How can I execute a node script (#!/usr/bin/env node) on Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, cmd

I want to check version of `protractor` command on my windows machine. I typed following but it didnt work. why? The path is correct.

```
./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor --version
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The file is a script -

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'test';

require('../built/cli.js');
```

I could run it using Bash in Windows but is there a way to run it on CMD?

Comment: In Windows, the path separator is a backslash, not a forward slash.

Comment: Remove `.`. It won't work in windows.

Comment: Thus, `node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor --version`. (In Windows, `.` is in the `PATH` by default).

Comment: that didnt work either `>.\protractor --version
'.\protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: No. The "shebang" notation that tells bash to run node will not be recognized by cmd. Windows only identifies executables by their file extension.  Plus, windows uses forward-slashes for paths so you are not specifying the executable properly either.

Comment: remove `.` doesn't help either - `>protractor --version
'protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Then it's not an executable script on Windows (for example, because it doesn't have a file extension marking it as executable and indicating an interpreter). That's not a problem with your command-line usage.

Comment: can I make the script executable?

Comment: By renaming it to have a file extension with a registered handler.

Comment: ...if you don't have any extension that node.js will execute, then that's a whole 'nother question.

Comment: cmd.exe is so different from bash, you can't expect anything like portability. The best you can do is start again "inspired" by the shell script.

Comment: BTW, why not `node node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor --version`? That is, call `node` explicitly.

Comment: yup, that worked! Can you specify it as answer? I'll accept it

Comment: Feel free to add it as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the command prompt of windows (`cmd.exe`) you should :

- use windows path separators (`\` instead of `/`).
- not prefix by `./` to run something.

Also keep in mind that the first line of your script is not understood by the windows shell. So you should explicitly call the node interpreter.

Assuming the node interpreter is in the PATH, in your case you should type :

```
node node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor --version
```

Comment: Using .\ is valid in cmd.exe for the current directory. Since the current working directory is implicitly included in the PATH, it does not need to be used.